# Laravel 4 Eager Loading filtering and selecting only matching results

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to output the filter results with only matching elements.

I have two tables (in the real project, which will be 5), let's say `companies` and `projects`. A company may have more than one project or may not have any.

These are the relations:

/app/models/Company.php

```
<?php

class Company extends Eloquent {

    public function projects() {
        return $this->hasMany('Project','companyID');
    }

    protected $table = 'companies';


}
```

/app/models/Project.php

```
<?php

class Project extends Eloquent {

    public function companies() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company','companyID');
    }

}
```

What I want to do is, I want to get results of them both but only with matching parameters.

I've tried this:

```
return Company::with(array('projects'=>function($query){
    $query->where('id',99); //project's id is 99
}))->get();
```

[This is the output JSON](http://paste.laravel.com/O2t)

If I change the value from `99` to `1` (there is a result with products.id of 1), it changes into [this](http://paste.laravel.com/O2u):

*I only want to get the second result from the second JSON i've posted*.

As you can see in the second JSON (I'm using [this parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to check), all companies are loaded regardless of the project, and only the rows matched have the object `projects`.

There will be more 'with's and I don't know how to filter only matching elements.

I also tried `having()` inside closure, but it's still same:

```
$query->having('projects.id','=',99);
```

Is there a way to filter only matching results (without using a loop) which the output will only include the results having the matched projects object?

**Edit:** Actually, 5 tables will be filtered.

`companies`, `projects`, `works`, `users` and `user_works`

Let's say;
"Companies" have many projects.
"Projects" have many works
"Works" have many users, also "Users" may have more than one work (pivot table user_works).

All relations are set correctly from models.

I want to do a global searching to these.

Something like: "Bring me the user id 1's works which has company id of 5 and project id of 4", but none of the fields are mandatory.
So these are also valid for searching: "Bring me everyone's works on project id of 2", or "bring me id 2's works", or "bring me all the works starting from today", "bring me the id 1's works on project 2", "Bring me this year's works done of company id 1".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `whereHas()` is the solution on my case. It filters relation and affects the results returned in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id of the project, would it make more sense to go that route?  `$project = Project::find(99);` and then the company variables would  be accessible with `$project->companies->name;`

It would make more sense to rename the `companies()` function to `company()` because a project will only ever belong to one.

Comment: Can you please check the discussion starting from [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=53511#p53511) ? It is more complex than it looks (4 tables are related actually).